# When using API private_app_api.Invoices.Create get error 'A validation exception occurred' but it look like it worked. How to handle this?

Tags: c#, xero-api

When using API **private_app_api.Invoices.Create** we get an error 'A validation exception occurred' but it looks like it partly worked. How do we handle this?
i.e I used the above API and got an exception error with description 'A validation exception occurred'.
However, when I look into Xero, many of the invoices I passed into it have gone through, but a few did not.
What should I do to cater for this. i.e. How can I check what has happened so I know what has gone through to Xero and what has not?
Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Are you using any specific SDK?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Code snip:

XeroCoreApi private_app_api;
private_app_api = new XeroCoreApi("https://api.xero.com", new PrivateAuthenticator(xeroConnection.CertificatePath, xeroConnection.Password),
                 new Consumer(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret), null,
                 new DefaultMapper(), new DefaultMapper());
List<Invoice> responseList = private_app_api.Invoices.Create(listInvoice).ToList();


The last line generates an unhandled exception when it fails to create one/many invoice from the invoice list (listInvoice) sent as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

You should add the [summarizeErrors=false](https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/requests-and-responses#postandput) parameter to your requests. That way the response will tell you which Invoices were created and which ones failed.

e.g.

```html
<Invoices>
    <Invoice status="OK">
      ...
    </Invoice>
    <Invoice status="OK">
      ...
    </Invoice>
    <Invoice status="WARNING">
      ...
    </Invoice>
    <Invoice status="ERROR">
      ...
    </Invoice>
 </Invoices>
```